# assign variable in a for-loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, methods

I am trying to assign the element with the lowest count into a new array property `lowestAlph` and give me the below iteration where `-2` is being stored, instead of simply outputting the lowest count `-2` on its own :

[["n"], ["o", "p"], ["q"], ["r", "s"], -2]

However, it's not printing the correct output with the `push` method.
Could someone please help?

```js
const example = {
    alph: [
        [["a"], ["b", "c"], ["d"], ["e", "f"], 23],
        [["g"], ["h", "j"], ["k"], ["l", "m"], 19],
        [["n"], ["o", "p"], ["q"], ["r", "s"], -2],
        [["t"], ["u", "w"], ["x"], ["y", "z"], 25]
    ],

    lowestAlph: [],


    calcLow: function () {
        let lowest = this.alph[0][4];
        for (let i = 0; i < this.alph.length; i++) {
            for (let n = i + 1; n < this.alph.length; n++) {
                if (this.alph[n][4] < lowest)
                    lowest = this.alph[n][4]
            }
                //this.lowestAlph.push(this.alph[i])
        }
        return lowest;
    }
}

console.log(example.calcLow());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently only retrieving the last element in the array `this.alph[n][4]` and assigning that to the `lowest` variable.

Instead you should assign the whole array to `lowest` using `this.alph[n]` and then retrieve the last element when doing the comparison.

See example below.

```js
const example = {
    alph: [
        [["a"], ["b", "c"], ["d"], ["e", "f"], 23],
        [["g"], ["h", "j"], ["k"], ["l", "m"], 19],
        [["n"], ["o", "p"], ["q"], ["r", "s"], -2],
        [["t"], ["u", "w"], ["x"], ["y", "z"], 25]
    ],

    lowestAlph: [],


    calcLow: function () {
        let lowest = this.alph[0];
        for (let i = 0; i < this.alph.length; i++) {
            for (let n = i + 1; n < this.alph.length; n++) {
                if (this.alph[n][4] < lowest[4])
                    lowest = this.alph[n]
            }
        }
        return lowest;
    }
}

console.log(example.calcLow());
```

Answer (score 2):

It will return expected output if correct below:

1. remove nested loop (one `for` loop can find out the lowest value, because your purpose is not sorting the `alph`)
2. if found lower value, uses `=` operator instead of `Array.push` because it will keep adding new value into your `lowestAlph` if lower value if found
3. return `this.lowestAlph` instead of `lowest`

```js
const example = {
    alph: [
        [["a"], ["b", "c"], ["d"], ["e", "f"], 23],
        [["g"], ["h", "j"], ["k"], ["l", "m"], 19],
        [["n"], ["o", "p"], ["q"], ["r", "s"], -2],
        [["t"], ["u", "w"], ["x"], ["y", "z"], 25]
    ],

    lowestAlph: [],


    calcLow: function () {
        let lowest = this.alph[0][4];
        for (let i = 0; i < this.alph.length; i++) {
            // for (let n = i + 1; n < this.alph.length; n++) { // remove this for-loop
                if (this.alph[i][4] < lowest)
                    this.lowestAlph = this.alph[i] // assign with the array instead of Array.push
            // }
                //this.lowestAlph.push(this.alph[i])
        }
        return this.lowestAlph; // return this.lowestAlph instead of lowest
    }
}

console.log(example.calcLow());
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to clone and sort the array by the 4th index values and return the lowest. For example

```js
const alpha = [
  [["a"], ["b", "c"], ["d"], ["e", "f"], 23],
  [["g"], ["h", "j"], ["k"], ["l", "m"], 19],
  [["n"], ["o", "p"], ["q"], ["r", "s"], -2],
  [["t"], ["u", "w"], ["x"], ["y", "z"], 25]
]

const sorted = [...alpha].sort((a, b) => b[4] - a[4])
console.log(JSON.stringify(sorted.pop()))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the spread operator

```js
const example = {
    alph: [
        [["a"], ["b", "c"], ["d"], ["e", "f"], 23],
        [["g"], ["h", "j"], ["k"], ["l", "m"], 19],
        [["n"], ["o", "p"], ["q"], ["r", "s"], -2],
        [["t"], ["u", "w"], ["x"], ["y", "z"], 25]
    ],

    lowestAlph: [],


    calcLow: function () {
        let lowest = this.alph[0][4];
        for (let i = 0; i < this.alph.length; i++) {
            for (let n = i + 1; n < this.alph.length; n++) {
                if (this.alph[n][4] < lowest)
                    lowest = this.alph[n][4]
            }
           this.alph[i].includes(lowest) ?
                this.lowestAlph = [...this.alph[i]] : null
        }
        return this.lowestAlph
    }
    
}

console.log(example.calcLow());
```